# startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord?

Tags: android-asynctask, avaudiorecorder

I have below code that gives init failure:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, mSamplingRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, iN);
        recorder.startRecording();
```

It's called by my Activity:

```
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... none) {
                record();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

It gives below exception:

E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
 E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
 E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
 E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
 E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
 E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

What could have gone wrong, please?
I believe it's not the problem of the audio recorder, but about async task/ multithreading. Because it works like charm before when I had a fragment including an onCreateView, and I put the AsyncTask call in onClick of a button.
Now I initial the UI in my activity's OnCreate(), I don't have fragment or onCreateView, I thought I'm already using a async thread but still...

Comment: in which device you are testing this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - repushing the apk from Android Studio after changing the permissions in the manifest doesn't actually change the permission in the app settings. 
I have to manually open Settings ->> App -> Permissions -> slide "Microphone to be on.